# Extract value of checked checkboxes in an excel file using python

Tags: python, excel, checkbox, jupyter-notebook

I’m extracting a PDS excel file using python jupyter but i could not able to extract the checked checkbox. I just want to extract the value “Single” if Single is checked or the value “Married” if Married is checked.
For Example : Marital Status: Single ☐ Married ☒
Output: Marital Status: Married

Answer (score 0):

You can see the "TRUE" or "FALSE" values like that:

right click on your check box > Format Control > Control > Cell Link

The selected cell will change as per the status of the assigned checkbox